# Calling println method within println

Tags: java, printing, tostring

I just wrote this code:

```
public class T 
{
  public String toString()
   {
     System.out.println("new line");
     return " "+4;
   }
}
```

and:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     T t = new T();
     System.out.println("11"+t);
}
```

and while I expected it to print

```
11 new line
4
```

it actually printed:

```
new line
11 4
```

why is that?
What is the order of this printing and what is the logic behind this?

Thanks!

Comment: How should your program be able to concatenate the Strings here `"11"+t` before calling `String.valueOf(Object)` for `t` (which itself calls `toString` on that object)? Right, it can't so it has to do that before the String concatenation and therefore obviously before passing that concatenated String to `println` from the `main` method.

Comment: Because `"11"+t` is evaluated before `println` is called the second time.

Comment: Use a debugger and step through your code, and you'll quickly learn the order of execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call for the toString happens before the "11" print.

The reason (like @Tom said), in order to concating the string, It have to create all the pieces first, and then it concating.

Only after the String is full ready - it will go to your screen.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function, Java evaluates all of its arguments before actually going into that function. So in you case, it first evaluates `"11"+t`. Now that calls t.toString(), which writes "new line". Then toString returns " 4", and that is concatenated to "11", then println is executed to write "11 4"